# Update mySQL table with Dynamic table input

Tags: php, mysql, html

Im having trouble updating mysql database with a dynamic table where i can add or remove rows before submitting the form.

i can make it work with hardcoded values but not when i try updating with a while loop I cant seem to get it to work

I first set the POST like this

```
results += "<tr><td>" + "<input style=\"border:none\" name=\"bar"+i+"\" id=\"bar"+i+"\" type=\"text\" value=\""+myArray[i]+"\" class=\"field left\" readonly>" + "</td>";  
results += "<td>" + "<input class=\"form-control\" type=\"text\" name=\"input"+i+"\" id=\"input"+i+"\"/>" + "</td>";

results += "<input class=\"form-control\" type=\"hidden\" value=\""+myArray.length+"\" name=\"arr\" id=\"arr\" readonly /><table><br /> <br />";
```

This is my sad attempt at a loop

```
<?php
$link = mysqli_connect(//correct info);

if(mysqli_connect_error()){
die("Could not connect to database");
}
?>
<script type="text/javascript">

<?php
$arrLength= $_POST['arr'];
$x=0;
while ($x<$arrLength){



$query= "UPDATE `inventory_items` SET `item_quantity` = '" . $_POST['input'+$x] . "' WHERE `Id` = '" . $row['bar'+$x] . "' ;";

mysqli_query($link,$query);

$x++;
};

?>
```

The hard code that worked for one row looked like this

```
<?php

$arrLength= $_POST['arr'];
$x=0;
while ($x<$arrLength){

$quantity= $_POST['input0'];
$barcode = $_POST['bar0'];

$query="UPDATE inventory_items ".
   "SET item_quantity = item_quantity + $quantity ".
   "WHERE item_barcode = $barcode" ;


$x++;
};


?>
```

How would i loop through this to up date the values or would it be better if set as an array then run though

is it possible to add the $x to the end of the name kind of like

```
 $quantity= $_POST['input'+$x];
```

thanks for the help

Comment: Using `mysqli_*` or `PDO` is not enough to prevent SQL injection. You need to sanitize the variables that you use in the queries, or even better, use parameterized queries

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update your query to:

```
$query= "UPDATE `inventory_items` SET `item_quantity` = '" . $_POST['input' . $x] . "' WHERE `Id` = '" . $row['bar' . $x] . "' ;";
```

You used + as in Javascript while . is used to concatonate in php. In your code you are doing addition of a string and integer variable.